# toggle value of disabled attribute when JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input tag on my website that uses javascript for autocomplete ...I want  `<input>` tags' disabled attribute as true when my users don't have javascript enabled on their systems.
but when Javascript is enabled I want the value of `disabled=false`.
how do I go about doing that?

what I've done so far:

```
<input name="xyz" class="xyzautocomplete" type="text" id="name" value="enter name" disabled="true">
```

will using

```
document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;
```

inside same `<input>` tag as `script=""` work for both cases??

IE,

```
 <input name="xyz" script="document.getElementById("name").disabled = false;" class="xyzautocomplete" type="text" id="0" value="enter name" disabled="True">
```

IF NOT, how would I do it??

Comment: Shouldn't it be `.disabled = false` since if JavaScript is run you _don't_ want it to be disabled?

Comment: Yes ! my bad, will edit asap.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question - what is the problem with the solution you came up with?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: YOur id is not xyz its is 0.

Comment: that's another error I've done while posting this question.Thanks a bunch

Comment: The actual ID is having jinja type format ie `$name-id`..

Comment: Depending on the version of HTML, an ID starting with a number may not be valid.This is unlikely to be causing your problem, but worth fixing for good practice's sake.

Comment: the identifiers are all given for the sake of the example, and is quite different in the actual file..the actual format is different. I'll change it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the javascript is disabled then none of the javascript syntaxes will work.

You have to do it with `Tag`

Please try with below solution -

```
<script>
     <!--
        document.write('<input name="xyz" class="xyzautocomplete" type="text" id="0" value="enter name" >')
     -->
  </script>

  <noscript>
    <input name="xyz" class="xyzautocomplete" type="text" id="0" value="enter name" disabled >
  </noscript>
```

Comment: I want javascript to toggle the disabled attribute when it is enabled to false. the default state of disabled attribute is true.

Comment: But in that case, when Javascript is disabled it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct with regards to the inline JavaScript. There is no `script` attribute, and `onload` isn't defined for inputs, so your script will need to be in a `<script>` element following the input.

However, what none of the existing answers mention is that `disabled` is a *boolean* attribute, that is, its presence or absence determines whether the input is disabled or not. Its value does not matter.

So setting the attribute to a value in JavaScript does not work. The attribute would still be there, just with a different value!
What you need to do is remove the attribute altogether.

```js
document.getElementById("name").removeAttribute('disabled');
```

```html
<input name="xyz" class="xyzautocomplete" type="text" id="name" value="enter name" disabled="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is never good way to put JS inline. Put it after the html element. Also you are targeting id of xyz with does not exists. Your id is 0.

```js
document.getElementById("0").disabled = false;
```

```html
<input name="xyz"  class="xyzautocomplete"  disabled  type="text" id="0" value="enter name">
```

As you can see input is disabled, but JS makes it enabled. People who don't have JS wont be able to use input.